# Is there a faster way to loop through the pages of a get request in python?

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, get

I want to get all the tv show ids from the themoviedb.org api that were released in the December 2017. There are around 3676 pages of json data. I can access a single page in each of my api request. So to loop through 3676 pages of data, I have to make that many number of api requests in the loop and it takes a huge amount of time. Is there a faster way to get all the tv show ids released in December 2017 by avoiding the looping? Below is my code in python:

```
import requests
import json

#tv urls
baseTvUrl = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?release_date.gte=2017-12-01&release_date.lte=2017-12-31&' + api_key
baseCreditUrlTv = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/'
baseCreditUrl2 = '/credits?' + api_key

myResponseTv = requests.get(baseTvUrl)

if(myResponseTv.ok):
    Data = json.loads(myResponseTv.content.decode('utf-8'))
total_pages_tv = Data['total_pages']
tv_ids = {*()}
print(total_pages_tv)
#Method to get all the tv id's by iterating through all the pages
for page in range(total_pages_tv):
    page = page+1
    #print(page)
    tvUrlPage = baseTvUrl + '&page=' + str(page)
    myResponseTv = requests.get(tvUrlPage)
    if(myResponseTv.ok):
        Data = json.loads(myResponseTv.content.decode('utf-8'))
        for results in Data['results']:
            if(results is not None):
                #print(type(results))
                for key, value in results.items():
                    if(key=='id'):
                        #print(key, 'is:', value)
                        tv_ids.add(value)
print(tv_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use scrapy. 
You need to create a spider and in the settings, you can modify `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`. it will be faster. If you haven't used scrapy, i suggest you to start with the following link https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html